# DropdDownlist doesnt show the selected value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I've got a dropdownlist in a html page,
I've been populating it with data being pulled from an array using the .match function.
I can see the correct values being shown in the drop-down list if i manually click on it.
However I want to be able to store the selected value on the drop-down and ave it be selected automatically if i return to it again when navigating to and back from a different html page. I am using localstorage to accomplish this.

The weird thing is that it does select the correct value when navigating pages but ONLY shows it as being selected when i click on the list instead of automatically showing the value in the drop-down list. 
I have a default value of "Select a Location" being displayed.

see the image below for an illustration of the issue. In this case the dropdown list has not selected text and the actual value that should be shown is highlighted in blue.
[image]

Im using the selectedIndex property to set the desired value in the dropdown but i cant figure out what is going on.

Heres my HTML markup, the onchange function just sets the currently selected value of the dropdown list for page navigation.

```
   <center>  Select a Plant Room</center>       
              <select name="sites" onchange="getPlantRoom()" id="projectLocations">
              <center> <option value="default" >Select a location</option></center>
             </select>
           <center> 
           <div>
```

Ive got a function which runs onload which does run but doesnt achieve the desired results.

```
var items= (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sites")));  
var select = document.getElementById("projectLocations");

for(index in items) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(items[index].match("site:(.*),siteAddr:")[1], index);
}
var selectedPlant = document.getElementById("projectLocations");
var indexProject= localStorage.getItem("projLocation");
selectedPlant.selectedIndex=indexProject;
```

I have looked at this issue myself for a while now and i cant see anything obvious.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried console.logging the indexProject var you're pulling from localStorage?

Comment: Hi Mark, Ive tried that and it seems to be working fine. it saves 0 for the default option, 1 for the first record and 2 for the second. Even navigating through pages works, when i return to the page with the drop down on it the correct indexProject var is returned. Its really doing my head in. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand the event responsible for making change in html to show selected value has not been triggered. This is the probable reason why "Select a Location" is displayed instead of the value you would want. In jQuery I would have used the following code:

```
$("#projectLocations").trigger("click");
```

you can add the following code as the last line in load fucntion.

```
selectedPlant.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```

Comment: Hi Arpit, Thanks for the response. Sometimes the drop down test is blank if i selected an option manually and navigate to a page and then navigate back. the "Select a Location" text is replaced by blank text. clicking on the drop down shows that the correct option is selected but not shown.  Ive tried the code you suggested but it doesnt work. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for it ?

Comment: Can you try identifying the option while creating it. i.e. try something of this sort 
`var isPreSelected =false;
if (index == localStorage.getItem("projLocation"))
isPreSelected = true;`
 then use this value as follows:
`select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(items[index].match("site:(.*),siteAddr:")[1], index,false,isPreSelected);`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so from what I understand. You want to store the selected item in state, and then use that as the default `select` when you visit that page again.

If that is the case, then I suggest storing the selected index in local storage, and then do a check for that key. if it exists it should be the default value for the `select`.